# Rails - Get the owner of the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

Hey. I'm starting in Rails and I guess my question is pretty easy. I have 2 models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
end
```

I'm trying to get the owner of the book on the show method, but everything I do says I can't find an Owner without an ID.

My controller has:

```
 def show
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@owner= Owner.find(params[:owner_id])
end
```

And my view:

```
<%= link_to owner.name, owner %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the relationship from the book to the owner, you don't even have to do this in the controller.

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

In your views:

```
<%= link_to @book.owner.name, @book.owner %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect. Playing around a little bit I noticed that if I do like `belongs_to :book_owner, :class_name => "Owner"` and `<%= link_to @book.book_owner.name, @book.book_owner %>` it won't work. Whats the big difference here?

Comment: The foreign key in your `books` table would need to be `book_owner_id` rather than `owner_id` for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `belongs_to :owner` you can use it like this:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @owner= book.owner
end
```

In your view you have to use these global `@` variables: `@book, @owner`. `book` and `owner` won't work.